# How do you get the Bone Charm in Mission 7, 'The Flooded District'?

Tags: dishonored

How do you get the Bone Charm? Please include a picture of where the Bone Charm is near the area where you kill the River Krusts, Weeper/Watch Officer, and loot the Weeper Camp which is right before the next area you need to go to in Mission 7 (The Flooded District).

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, you're looking for the last Bone Charm in mission 7 which is located past a sewer gate near the fifth Rune in this mission:
[image: Location of last Bone Charm in mission 7]

Picture was taken from [this YouTube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmKmW_YvWlw).